# Which one certificate to buy for SAML encryption and signing

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, saml, saml-2.0, federation

Is it enough good to buy SSL X509 certificate for SAML 2.0 SP encryption and signing or I have to look for other certificate type such as Code Signing Certificate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do not** need a code signing cert.

Depending on how you've set up trust/which bindings you use/federation rules you could get away with a self signed cert. The answer is it depends, but a standard CA issued cert should be fine for the majority of use cases.